# How to create javascript function within json by Gson?

Tags: javascript, json, function, gson

Is it possible to create json like this via Gson? A javascript function without a key is within the json.

```
{
    autosave: {
        save( editor ) {
            return editor.saveData( editor.id, editor.getData() );
        },
        waitingTime: 2000
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, functions are not included in JSON.

Comment: I know it's an invalid json. But I think it's doable though it's not recommended.

Comment: Why? It's invalid, and you can't do that with any stringifier. You could add the functions to the JSON string after stringifying an object, but what's it worth of, no parser can parse that JSON. A typical way to deliver functions in JSON is to implement the function(s) in the app, and include the name of the function as a string. Then after parsing the JSON in the app, you can replace the string values representing a function with real functions.

Comment: It's a special requirement. Thanks for your reply. I know how to achieve it now.

Comment: Gson is totally a wrong tool for such a requirement. Why not use a JavaScript code generator or merely produce valid JavaScript with templates or whatever more appropriate? JSON stands for "JS object notation", not "JS", and it cannot handle anything other than objects, arrays and literals.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I find a way to do it by using TypeAdapterFactory.
Here is the code.

```
class AutosaveAdapter implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> tokenType) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> adapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, tokenType);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                return adapter.read(reader);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter writer, T value) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = adapter.toJsonTree(value);

                if (value instanceof Autosave) {
                    String dom = value.toString();
                    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) tree;
                    jo.addProperty("autosave", dom );
                }
                gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class).write(writer, tree);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And

```
class Autosave {

    int waitingTime;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    String name;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    String arguments;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    String body;

    Autosave(int waitingTime, String name, String arguments, String body) {
        this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
        this.name = name;
        this.arguments = arguments;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{ waitingTime:" + waitingTime + "," +
                  name +" ( "+arguments+" ) { " + body + " } "+
                "}";
    }
    
}
```

To test:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        Autosave autosave = new Autosave(2000, "save", "editor", "return editor.saveData( editor.id, editor.getData() );");
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setLenient();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new AutosaveAdapter())
                .create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(autosave));
    }
```

Comment: Did you notice that the output **differs** from what you asked in your question and doesn't match it?